# QGIS Space Syntax plugin with OSM data?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, layers, syntax

I'd like to do a space syntax analysis for a city I observe, but when I use the [Space Syntax Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spacesyntax/), the desired shapelayer roads doesn't show up.

It's an OSM vector layer, what do I have to do to be able to select it for space syntax?

Apparently [Axwoman](http://fromto.hig.se/~bjg/axwoman/), a plugin for ArcMap can do this:

> with the help of Axwoman, axial lines of a large city can be
>   automatically generated within a few minutes from the road central
>   lines, [using] the new definition of axial lines based on
>   walkability or drivability.

Is there a plugin/program like this for QGIS?

Comment: Did you also install [depthmapXnet](http://archtech.gr/varoudis/depthmapX/)? (Windows/OSX) I think that's needed by the Space Syntax plugin to do the visibilty analysis, but I'm not able to check :/